# A/C working but engine overheating

Tags: chevrolet, ac, coolant

I have a 2004 Chevy 2500 6.0 and the AC compressor belt was not on when I bought the truck, so I put one on today and it worked great until I was parking, the dash said "Engine Coolant Hot" and coolant started spraying from the pipes just above the compressor and there was a vacuum suction on the radiator hose. Any ideas of what could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is this a Silverado? Could you better explain what you mean by "vacuum suction on the radiator hose"? Which hose is getting suctioned (top/bottom)?

Comment: Also, some pictures would help a lot I think in this case.